# Determining Statement Truth or Falsity?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I have to determine if these are true or false, for "∀x∃y" I read it as "for all X there is a Y". **The domain
consists of pairs x and y, where x is -1, 0, or 1 and y is -1, 0, or 1.** My answers are on the right in italics, however I dont know if they are correct, could someone explain?
(a) ∀x∃y(x + y = 0)  *true*
(b) ∃x∀y(x + y = y)  *true*
(c) ∀x∃y(xy ≥ y)  *true*
(d) ∃x∀y(x ≤ y)  *false*

Comment: @DanielSchepler sorry forgot to include that, just edited the post.

Comment: If you can explain why you got those answers, we can tell you if your reasoning is correct.  For example a) is true because for each $x = -1,0,1$ there is a $y = 1,0,-1$ respectively so that $x + y = 0; (-1+1=0+0=1+(-1) = 0$.  If that (or something similar to it) was your reasoning.  But if your reasoning was weird and you got "true" for weird reasons, you aren't correct.

Comment: That domain is a bit problematic, because then the natural interpretation of the binary function symbol $+$ does not always take values which are in that domain of discourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all your answers are correct.

The qualifier $\forall x \exists y$ means "If you pick a value of $x$, I can *always* find a value of $y$ that satisfies the condition". So, for example, $\forall (x \in \mathbb{N}) \exists (y \in \mathbb{N}) \ (y = x + 1)$ means "For any natural number $x$, I can find another natural number $y$ that's one more than it.

So, if $x, y \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, then we can actually check the truth of the statements explicitly by just checking "Is this true when $x = -1$? When $x = 0$? When $x = 1$?"

For example:

$\forall x \exists y (x + y = 0)$: When $x = -1$, we can pick $y = 1$. When $x = 0$, we can pick $y = 0$. When $x = 1$, we can pick $y = -1$. So this is true.

By comparison, $\exists x \forall y$ means "There is a single value of $x$ such that the statement is true for every possible $y$". So $\exists x \forall y (x + y = 0)$ is not true, because if $x = -1$ then $-1 + y$ is not always $0$, and the same is true for the other possible $x$ values. But thankfully, that's not the question you were asked to answer (I'm just using it for comparison).

$\exists x \forall y (x +  y = y)$ *is* true, because $x = 0$ works for all values of $y$.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, great answer!

Comment: I'd think (d) would be true because $x=-1$ works.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think I saw something different in there before, or just confused myself.